# How to stop evaluating within .emacs for debugging purposes?

Tags: debugging

I think I have a problem in my .emacs file and would like to place in it some function that would cause emacs to stop evaluating. I could then start a binary search to see where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Please clarify. I don't understand what you intend by "place it in some function" or "cause emacs to stop evaluating". (Have you tried just bisecting your init file, to find the problem?)

Comment: It seems that `(top-level)` works just fine to run a bisect of the file. I located the problem area and fixed it.

Comment: How does this question help others? What was the problem? How did you fix it? The question isn't clear, and the answer isn't either.

Comment: The question seems quite clear, how do you stop emacs from further evaluating code. The `(top-level)` when encountered will stop further evaluation. What the problem was does not matter, I wanted a way to simply put something in my .emacs top prevent evaluating code so I did not have to resort to commenting out or deleting text. Using `(top-level)` allowed me to bisect my .emacs until I found what was causing my issue. Anyone else stumbling across this may find it useful to stop code evaluation.

Comment: As a further example I have this in my .emacs also now to stop further evaluatiion when I am using a different emacs version. ```;; ;; WARNING!! don't execute anything below here if using plain old emacs
(if (string-equal "/usr/bin/emacs" (getenv "EMACS"))
    (top-level)) 
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it. Entering

> (top-level)

seems to accomplish the goal